# Find max number of products owned by each customer

Tags: python, pandas

I have a transactional database of customer purchases + sales of a product for a given year of the form below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id': [43,12,40,43, 12],
                  'days_since_year_began': [23,32,13,45,90],
                  'action' : ['buy', 'buy', 'buy', 'sell', 'sell'],
                  'product_id': [4324, 123, 12, 4324, 123]})
```

```
   customer_id  days_since_year_began action  product_id
0          43                     23    buy        4324
1          12                     32    buy         123
2          40                     13    buy          12
3          43                     45   sell        4324
4          12                     90   sell         123
```

I need to find the max number of products held by all customers in the year (every row in this dataset). Initially I was thinking a groupby customer_id and action, but it only ended up giving the counts of each.

Answer expected (just for the 5 rows above - not a very good example but you get the drift):

```
customer_id | max_held | days_since_year_began
43 | 1 | 23
12 | 1 | 32
40 | 1 | 13
```

The brute force solution is obvious, but how would I proceed to do this efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you copy/paste the text of the included 5 rows?

Comment: if you make the action binary (i.e `buy=1`) then you should be able just to `df.group_by(customer_id).agg('sum')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps guiding you to the right direction. Mapping `buy` and `sell` to `+1` and `-1` and applying a cumulative sum can help you get a time series of how many products a customer holds.

```
df['cumhold'] = (df.replace({'buy': 1, 'sell': -1})
                   .groupby('customer_id')
                   .action.cumsum())

df.loc[df.groupby('customer_id', as_index=False).cumhold.max().index]
```

Comment: Hey thanks! :) This solution assumes that the dataframe is sorted by `days_since_year_began` though, is there a way without pre sorting?

Comment: Kind of messy to work with time series without them being, well sorted by time, right? Imagine having a chart of stock prices with data on 2012, then 2017, then 2001, then 2019... Hard to extract any insights, and especially hard to use vectorized methods on this

Comment: I see, makes sense. Was thinking if there was a way to avoid sorting as its a really large dataset. Thanks for your input! :)